# Scaling a tikzpicture changes the proportional size of the spaces between the drawn figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm,tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{square/.pic={\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.75]
   \pic at (0,0) {square};
   \pic at (2,0) {square};
   \pic at (0,-2) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf` whose contents are as follows:

[image: No scale]

If the `%` symbol is now deleted from the document at `~/test.tex`, and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, the contents of the file at `~/test.pdf` are as follows:

[image: With scale]

Note that when no scaling is applied to the `tikzpicture`, the horizontal and vertical spaces between the squares is equal to the length of the squares' sides. However, when a scaling is applied these spaces are shorter than the length of the squares' sides.

1. Why does this discrepancy occur?
2. How can I scale a `tikzpicture` in a fully proportional way?

Comment: Pics are similar to nodes. Can you try adding `transform shape` to the options of the `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel With `transform shape` the scaling works as desired. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated suggestion. LaTeX produces a number of auxiliary files. If the main `tex` is processed  in `$HOME` (aka in `~`), those file will be created there. It's better if you create a folder, move the tex file there, and then run `pdflatex` from inside the folder. Then you will only need to remove the folder to get rid of the whole test project.

Comment: @Celdor Thanks. My TeX projects are compartmentalized in folders. I used `~` in this example in order to simplify the description of the process.